# Google maps search for location

Tags: google-maps

How can I expand ths function with a search field for a location?

```
    <tr>
      <td class="XSdataCol1" valign="top" align="bottom">[[description]]: [[help]]</td>
      <td class="XSdataCol2">
        <form>
            please add here tour search location <br>
            <input type="text" name="adres" value=""><input type="Submit" name="Submit"value="Submit" onclick="zoekAdres_[[fieldname]]()]">
        </form>
        <div onclick="removeMarker_[[fieldname]]()">remove marker</div>
        <input type="hidden" maxlength="255" name="[[fieldname]]" value="[[value]]">
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=<xsproc name="C_GoogleMaps::getAPIKey"></xsproc>" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

          var map_[[fieldname]];
          var markerCount_[[fieldname]]=0;
          var marker_[[fieldname]];

          function updateLocatie(point) {
            console.log(point);
            if (point) {
              document.forms.mainform.[[fieldname]].value="("+ point.y + "," + point.x +")";
            }
          }

          function removeMarker_[[fieldname]]() {
            markerCount_[[fieldname]]=0;
            document.forms.mainform.[[fieldname]].value="";
            map_[[fieldname]].clearOverlays();
          }
          function zoekAdres_[[fieldname]](){

          }

          function load_[[fieldname]]() {
            if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
              map_[[fieldname]]=new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_[[fieldname]]"));
              map_[[fieldname]].enableScrollWheelZoom();
              map_[[fieldname]].enableContinuousZoom();
              map_[[fieldname]].enableDoubleClickZoom();
              map_[[fieldname]].addControl(new GLargeMapControl());

              var lat_center=<xsproc name="C_GoogleMaps::getLatCenter" params="[[value]]"></xsproc>;
              var long_center=<xsproc name="C_GoogleMaps::getLongCenter" params="[[value]]"></xsproc>;

              var lat_point=<xsproc name="C_GoogleMaps::getLatCenter" params="[[value]]"></xsproc>;
              var long_point=<xsproc name="C_GoogleMaps::getLongCenter" params="[[value]]"></xsproc>;

              var zoomlevel=<xsproc name="C_GoogleMaps::getLastZoomlevel"></xsproc>;
              map_[[fieldname]].setCenter(new GLatLng(lat_center,long_center),zoomlevel);

              GEvent.addListener(map_[[fieldname]],'click', function(overlay,point) {
                  //check of we al een marker hebben
                  if (point && markerCount_[[fieldname]]==0) {
                    updateLocatie(point);
                    marker_[[fieldname]]=new GMarker(point,{icon:G_DEFAULT_ICON, draggable: true});
                    GEvent.addListener(marker_[[fieldname]], "dragend", function() {
                        updateLocatie(marker_[[fieldname]].getPoint());
                        //map_[[fieldname]].panTo(marker_[[fieldname]].getPoint()); 
                      }
                    );
                    map_[[fieldname]].addOverlay(marker_[[fieldname]]);
                    markerCount_[[fieldname]]++;
                  }
                }
              );

              //Check of er een marker in de database was opgeslagen
              var p="[[value]]";
              if (p!="") {
                var point=new GLatLng(lat_point,long_point);
                marker_[[fieldname]]=new GMarker(point,{icon:G_DEFAULT_ICON, draggable: true});
                GEvent.addListener(marker_[[fieldname]], "dragend", function() {
                    updateLocatie(marker_[[fieldname]].getPoint());
                    map_[[fieldname]].panTo(marker_[[fieldname]].getPoint()); 
                  }
                );
                map_[[fieldname]].panTo(point); 
                map_[[fieldname]].addOverlay(marker_[[fieldname]]);
                markerCount_[[fieldname]]++;
              }
            }
          }
        </script>
        <div id="map_[[fieldname]]" style="width:396px; height:300px"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          window.onload=load_[[fieldname]];
          window.onunload=GUnload;
      </script>       

      </td>
      <td class="XSdataCol">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "expand this function" ?

Comment: maybe the worng word. But add a function or so, to search for an address and then drop the marker on the map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you already had a look at the [Geocoding example](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding_Object) found on google map API website :

```
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

function showAddress(address) {
  geocoder.getLatLng(
    address,
    function(point) {
      if (!point) {
        alert(address + " not found");
      } else {
        map.setCenter(point, 13);
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        map.addOverlay(marker);
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(address);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Is this function what you are looking for ?